# SMS: search v pre-built group (Queue overflow)

Tags: sms

I know SMS infrastructure was built off of CiviMail but there is a key difference when building a recipient list from search.

[image]

- Email - schedule/send via CiviMail > creates hidden group
- SMS - schedule/send > puts contact's phone numbers in an array similar to "send email" to 50 or less option.

[image]

Issues:

- If you use the `SMS - schedule/send` option it does not show in `Find Mass SMS` screen
  https://example.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fmailing%2Fbrowse&reset=1&sms=1.
- We had a very high non deliverable rate (using Twilio) due to a Queue overflow error: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/30001. MPS rates for some orgs is only 1-3MPS, for us it is 75MPS but even so doing a search action mass sms to a good deal above your MPS will cause the Queue overflow error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sending mass texts to any significant amount of contacts, use Mailings > New Mass SMS. Create a group ahead of time.

Comment: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/3011